# Python cv2.VideoCapture() has wrong resolution and read cropped images

Tags: python, opencv, camera, resolution

I'm trying to read images from an IDS GV-5240CP camera plugged to my laptop via ethernet using Python and OpenCV.

This is what I am supposed to get :

[A 1280x1024 image (here resized for upload)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE9Sn.png)

But using this code:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

_, frame = cap.read()

print(frame.shape)

cv2.imshow("Out", frame)

cv2.waitKey(2000)
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

cv2.imwrite('Test2.png', frame)
```

I get:

[A 640x480 cropped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKidM.png)

How can I set my video capture to the native resolution?

Answer (score 0):

`VideoCapture` uses 640x480 by default.

If you want a different resolution, specify it in the constructor or use the `set()` method with `CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` and so on. Details in the docs.

```py
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1, apiPreference=cv2.CAP_ANY, params=[
    cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280,
    cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1024])
```

Answer (score -2):

out = cv2.VideoWriter(("E:", 'output.avi'), fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))
try using this and change the resolution according to your need,
tho it will download or use
cv2.resize(frame,(w,h),fx=0,fy=0, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

since you don't want to do this then use set() module in OpenCV to set specific resolution. docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/dfe/… this link for the full info about set()

Comment: Only works if the resolution is 640x480, which is not what I want: the picture is still cropped. Also, I don't want to record a video, only to grab frames properly

Comment: Since you updated your answer, I say again: I don't want a resize, I want the picture directly read for camera not to be cropped by default

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: since you don't want to do this then use set() module in OpenCV to set specific resolution.
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#ac4107fb146a762454a8a87715d9b7c96
this link for the full info about set()